# Documentation - do we "Click", "Push", "Press" or "Select" a button on a touch-screen interface

Tags: buttons, touch-screen, documentation, naming

I'm writing some documentation for a web-based application that will run on Android tablets at the factory at which I am employed.

I am having trouble wording the steps where the users must interact with the onscreen buttons via touch.

For example "1. Enter or scan your clock number and then"... "click the button", "press the button"?

Click sounds most natural to me, but it still doesn't "feel" right.

Is the word "click" ubiquitous while explaining interaction with an onscreen button regardless of if there is a mouse involved?

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37963/what-word-can-be-used-to-mean-either-click-or-tap

Comment: Usually buttons on a touch screen are designed to look like a real button, even being animated in such a way that it looks depressed when we touch it, so perhaps press would also be appropriate?

Comment: There's probably no right answer to this question. Can't you go with something like "validate", that would be neutral ?

Comment: "Tap" is also another option.

Comment: We rather "tap". Well from the options given, "press" is most suitable.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's no 'right' answer here. What is more important is that you are consistent within your own documentation.

Regarding touch interfaces, the typical interaction is 'tap'.

Regarding desktops, the typical interaction is 'click'.

In both cases, it's not the ONLY interaction, however, as both touch devices and desktops can be navigated in other ways (such as via the keyboard).

Personally, I prefer a more generic term such as 'select' that can be used agnostically across devices--though some have pointed out that 'select' is often reserved specifically for selecting an option.

Comment: Additionaly, please note that, tap and touch are different things. To tap, you have to remove your finger from the screen after touching it.

Comment: Surely the 'right' answer is the terminology the OP decides to use?

Comment: @user43251 only to the OP.

Comment: @DA01 Obviously not; he agrees with you it seems.

Comment: @user43251 point being there is no right answer that is universal here. SE is a site where answers, ideally, are applicable in general, not specific to the individual. I suppose the universal answer in this situation is "use whatever your team wants to use, but be consistent"

Comment: Yes, this was chosen as the answer because of the "consistent" clause.  I went with "tap", and I think it works nicely.  That word was escaping me entirely when I posted this question, else I may not have even asked it.

Comment: Cool. Just ironic that the right answer claims there's no right answer.

Comment: @user43251 ha! True. I suppose 'there is no right answer' *can* be the 'right answer'. :) Great. Just great. A paradox before I've even had my morning coffee...

Comment: @user43251 Haha! I guess I didn't look at it that way!

Comment: Also there's the conflict of "tap" and "long-press" in the mobile context. You press a button when you tap it, but you don't long-tap it when you "long press" it. The problem may be that tapping feels more touch-enabled than "lightly and quickly press to tap". Maybe press would be more accurate, since you click or press a button with a mouse (because you the mouse button makes "click"), but you denfinitely don't click a touchable interface unless you're using a mouse to control the device. so a tap is a click on a touchscreen. 1/2

Comment: Press seems to be applicable to both of them. But select is definitely wrong here. Because you don't long-tap, for consistencies sake, I'd choose press for all actions. That would even help with touchscreen enabled desktop pc's when you don't want to click on the mouse to click the button 2/2

Answer (score 23):

As you will be using Android, perhaps refer to their own [Design Principles documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/InteractivityInput.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH55-SW1)? They use 'touch';

> Access the entire collection of apps and widgets by touching the All Apps button at the center of the Favorites Tray.

I would also say you 'touch the button' because isn't that exactly what you are doing on a touch screen device? That surely is the equivalent to clicking a button with a mouse. E.g;

> 1. Enter or scan your clock number and then touch the 'Confirm' button to continue...

FWIW, Apple use 'tap' in their [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/InteractivityInput.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH55-SW1):

> People use gestures—such as tap, drag, and pinch—to interact with apps and their iOS devices.

Comment: Well... everyone here, outside of the IT department, calls our Android tablets "iPads". So I might want to stick with Apple's 'tap'.

Comment: Haha! I don't think you can go wrong with touch or tap - they both suggest interaction with a touchscreen device rather than a desktop.

Comment: To me, tap implies touching quickly and removing your finger. Touch doesn't do that for me. If I was told to tap a table I would quickly touch it then retract my hand. If I was told to touch it I would at least rest my hand there momentarily. I think either touch or tap works, but I think tap makes more sense.

Answer (score 15):

**Click** implies the pressing of a physical switch which then creates a 'click' *sound* - typically on devices with input devices attached (such as a mouse)

**Push** implies moving something out of its original position, typical of a physical button, again  similar to a mouse (or moreso key) input

**Press** implies moving into physical contact with something, the thing being moved and the target are up for interpretation, as such this can refer to any number of motions involving contact

**Select** implies the choice of something over something of equal standing, typically an item from a list so is likely less appropriate for the on/off or yes/no functionality of a switch

As such, for device agnostic purposes, I'd go with 'press' if limited to the supplied list.

**Tap** as noted above in the answers tends to be associated with touch screen devices, in which case it would be entirely appropriate to mention in relation to button interaction

Comment: "Click" and "press" are probably the two most widely used. "Click" is really a holdover from the _act_ of pressing the mouse button, which happens to activate the virtual button. A physical button would be "pressed". Either is fine for a classic mouse-driven interface, and should be understood by a touch screen user (where "tap" would be even better). However, "tap" could be confusing to someone using a mouse-driven interface, so be careful about using that word in general. "Select" is not good, except for a multiple choice option.

Comment: @PhilPerry - click has an onomatopoeic origin from a physical action, as such I'd likely align it more with use of a physical switch/button changing position than finger-screen contact, the OP is focussed on touch only

Comment: I agree that `press` is probably the best general-purpose answer.

Comment: 'Press' is not standard terminology for operating an on-screen control in any desktop or mobile OS that I'm aware of though. It always jars when a website or program asks me to press something (unless it refers to a physical key or button).

Comment: Right- however if restricted to the options listed it is the most suitable

Answer (score 2):

The Android setup screen used to instruct the user to **touch** the Android to begin, but I personally use **tap** for everything touch-related, as it's smaller, thus making instructions as simplistic as possible.

It is worth noting that if your buttons merely say **Tap here** then you should consider changing the text to just state their purpose, for instance **Add to contacts**.

Finally, if it is not clear to the user that they must tap a button, then you should consider redesigning your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

On a mobile device you use gestural movements, in this case it would be TAP. You can use the word click but it will be read as being out of date or out of touch.

Comment: If the interface is intended to _also_ be used with a mouse-driven PC, "tap" could induce confusion (i.e., mouse users are not used to that). If it is to be exclusively on a touch screen device, "tap" is fine.

Answer (score 1):

A button (that will trigger some action) is **pressed**, **pushed** or **activated**.

To do so in a web form, you can either point your mouse at it and **click** it (on a desktop PC) or **tap** at the element (on a touch device).

I would not use the term "select", that sounds as if you were choosing one from a set of buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would think that 'tap' is the preferred description, as this also infers a touch of a short duration. If asked to touch something, a user could reasonably continue touching the thing for a significant period of time. Many UIs interpret a touch-and-hold as an alternate gesture (e.g. iOS).

'Click', 'push' and 'press' all suggest some sort of mechanical operation, and 'select' suggests that a choice of several options is being made.

Answer (score 1):

**If it's a button, "press" and "push" will always be correct.**

A button, like many UI elements, mimics real life objects. "pressing" a button in any computer application has nothing to do with the method of input. Whether it's a screen you're touching, a mouse, a trackball or a straw, in the end, you're going to "hover" over the element (hence :hover in css), and make that button go down.

If you look at the default look of buttons, they even mimic real life. Often there's a light shining from the top, giving it some shadow underneath, and a gradient on the slightly rounded button. Regardless of your operating system, they'll look slightly 3-dimensional (flat design being the exception to this rule) and the down states include some shadow, representing a difference in depth.

"Clicking" is impossible without some form of real life (mouse-) button.

"Selecting" is more like :focus in css, where you're not pressing, choosing without having.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with "select", since in fact many touchscreen applications are now touch-to-highlight/drag-to-choose/lift-to-commit. That interaction sequence deals with initially erroneous touches, and calibration issues, MUCH more smoothly than anything else. You *can* tap with that system, but you get better accuracy if you don't... and it subtly trains you into using the version with built-in confirmation/correction. (I know IBM developed this approach as part of the ITS project and the 1992 World's Fair kiosks; I don't know whether anyone had independently stumbled on it and published earlier.)

(Boston's public transit system has had serious ongoing problems with their choice of "tap" as the verb for presenting a proximity card to a reader. People who do what "tap" normally means don't give the system enough time to read the card. "Hold" would have been a much better description of the actual interaction. Unfortunately, since people do learn despite their documentation, they haven't been motivated to change it.)

Comment: Never use "select" for a pushbutton. That word should be reserved for picking one or more _selections_ from a list of choices (whether a pull-down selection list, radio buttons, or checkboxes).