# Documenting button interactions

Tags: buttons, documentation, click, select, technical-writing

Instead of using "click" or "tap" in my documentation, I use the word "select" to select an option from the menu, buttons, etc. However, I am faced with a situation where the name of the button that needs to be selected is "Select" (not the best name for a button, I know :)
Has anyone experienced a similar situation? If so, how did you deal with it? Should I revert to "click" or "Choose"?

Comment: fwiw: "select" has some minor implication of "make a text selection". I don't see any issue for choose. Tap vs click are obviously device-dependent.

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57666/documentation-do-we-click-push-press-or-select-a-button-on-a-touch-s

Answer (score 1):

In places where we don't necessarily want to be explicit about the solution I've often used the phrase "interacts with the control" (and yes, "Select" seems like the right language for choosing options).

"Click" and "Tap" (as noted) are device-specific, and "choose" seems more analogous with selecting from a group of options than with interacting with a specific control. I've seen "Activates" for this language, but that feels like it has other implications that may not be right here.

"Interacts with" is a little clunky but avoids some of the device- and solution-specific concerns.