# Minimalistic User interfaces discussion

Tags: gui-design

I'm wondering whether or not a minimalistic user interfaces is the best choice.

For example you might have an application that has only one button per page, so a user can't get confused. Or multiple buttons on one form or other variants.

What are your preferences ( with reasons) for your preference of UI design.

Comment: Hi Rhys, Welcome to UX.se! I think your question is quite similar to the one I asked a couple days ago http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37868/minimalism-maximalism-or-whatever. If you feel it is different, can you edit your question to be more specific in that direction?

Comment: *battle cry* for the lolz!

Comment: I'll check it out. I posted it on normal stack, and got told to post it here instead.

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37868/minimalism-maximalism-or-whatever/37871#37871

Answer (score 1):

I liken it to open or closed questioning. What mode are you in when engaging the user in the particular task you are designing? Who is leading the discussion?

If you want the user to explore, to lead the task, then offering multiple options on a page can be better. If you want to focus the user and lead *them* through a task, then one action per page will usually yield better results.

Consider a typical ecommerce situation, the user would have multiple options to browse, search, explore the store. Once they've made their choice(s) and decided to check out, you need to focus them on that task. Remove navigation that might tempt them away from getting the transaction finished!

So in my view, there is a time and a place for both and often on the same site!